# Changing Vaadin Valo theme variables for menu bar

Tags: sass, vaadin7, vaadin-valo-theme

I'm having trouble using valo and its [API](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#valo-menu) to change one variable in the menubar. I just want v-font-weight to be 600px. I guess that I don't understand the API and what component to remove.

This is my scaled down attempt to do this in styles.scss.

```
@import "valo";
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, menu-item-style);

.myvalo {
  @include valo;

  $v-font-weight: 600;
  @include valo-menubar-menuitem-style();
}
```

When I inspect a menu bar item the styles applied looks like this:

[image: styles applied]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using

```
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, menu-item-style);
```

won't work because `menu-item-style` is not a component that you can remove from a valo theme. Valo components' list is declared in `$v-included-components` variable in `_variables.scss` file. You can check it on [vaadin's github](https://github.com/vaadin/framework/blob/2e5b49113439310d2dae9ec86fca3ccdf74833f5/themes/src/main/themes/VAADIN/themes/valo/shared/_variables.scss) or on [Valo API site](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#variable-v-included-components). The closest component to `menu-item-style` is `menubar`.

You can do something like that:

```
@import "valo";
$v-included-components: remove($v-included-components, menubar);

.myvalo {
    @include valo;

    $v-font-weight: 600;
    @include valo-menubar;
}
```

but it will set font weight to 600 for the whole `MenuBar` component.

To set it only on menu bar item I would use simple css rule:

```
.v-menubar-menuitem-caption {
    font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: That worked great. Thank you. I knew that I was missing something and the v-included-components list in _variables.scss is exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should made it as a workaround:

```
.myvalo {
  @include valo;

  .valo-menu-item-caption {
        font-weight: 600;
  }
}
```

Although `$v-font-weight` is used by [valo-menu-item-style](https://vaadin.com/api/valo/#variable-v-font-weight), so it should made the job.

Comment: I'm trying this but can't see it working yet. It might be due to my implementation but I don't ever see the valo-menu-item-caption applied to the menu. I added a screen shot of the styles applied to a menu bar item to this issue

Comment: I don't know how much you are into sass, so I don't mean this rude, but do you compiled ( https://vaadin.com/docs7/-/part7/framework/themes/themes-compiling.html) your sass.
Nevertheless it looks all like a wrong configuration to me, as well.